# Integration testing of Flink jobs

Tags: junit, apache-flink

New to Flink and trying to work out the best way to integration test a Job. What I want is to programmatically define some input and assert the output is as expected. Intuitively, I would create a class like the following

```
public abstract class EventSource<T> implements SourceFunction<T>
    List<T> theEvents;
    EventSource<T>(List<T> aList)
    @Override public void run(SourceContext<T> ctx)
        for each e in theEvents
            ctx.collect(e)
```

I can then define a `SinkFunction<T>` in the same manner, and verify as described in https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/datastream/testing/#testing-flink-jobs. Does this seem reasonable or are there better constructs in the ecosystem for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [your shared link on testing](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/datastream/testing/#testing-flink-jobs), Flink's MiniCluster can be an excellent way to handle this by allowing you to easily test/query specific collections and streams after processing and it will likely work for your use cases. You can find plenty of examples by just [searching for something like "minicluster" within the Apache Flink source code directly](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aapache%2Fflink+minicluster+path%3A%2F%5Eflink-tests%5C%2Fsrc%5C%2Ftest%5C%2Fjava%5C%2Forg%5C%2Fapache%5C%2Fflink%5C%2Ftest%5C%2F%2F&type=code).

Two other common patterns that I've historically used for larger, more complex jobs include:

##### Job Graph Tests

Basically create a function that handles all of the job-graph related construction of your application, specifically around inputs and outputs, so that you can easily replace those streams/sinks/sources with functions similar to what you have defined and easily query those after the job has been executed:

```
// Example Job Graph Function
fun StreamExecutionEnvironment.buildJobGraph(
   source1: SingleOutputStreamOperator<...>,
   source2: SingleOutputStreamOperator<...>,
   ...
): Pair<SingleOutputStreamOperator<...>, ...> {
   // Logic for all of your various join operations, mappings, etc.

   // Return your output streams which can be fed into downstream sinks
   return Pair(someResult, someOtherResult)
}

// Example Test
@Test
fun `output some result into some sink`() {
    val env = buildExecutionEnvironment()
    // Similar to your example above, this will be a SinkFunction with a publicly 
    // accessible collection that can be queried
    val resultSink = SomeMockSink() 

    // Build your example collections to process here (will be processed by the job
    // graph function
    val source1 = env.fromCollection(...)
    val source2 = env.fromCollection(...)

    // Build the graph and result sink
    val (result1, result2) = env.buildJobGraph(source1, source2)
    result1.addSink(resultSink)

    // Execute your graph
    env.execute()

    // Apply your assertions against the sink
    assertEquals(4, resultSink.values.size)
}
```

##### Test Container Tests

Another common approach, especially if you are interacting with larger, external systems might be to leverage [Test Containers](https://testcontainers.com/) to spin up temporal instances of your various points of interaction (e.g. databases, Kafka clusters, etc.) that you can use to query against after the execution of your tests. These can be *much* more complicated to run and quite a bit more work to configure, but at least you would be truly testing through issues that might arise when interacting with actual instances of these technologies and allow you to catch bugs that might otherwise not arise from simple mocks.